# Finding matches in two columns and replace

Tags: c, logic

I have two columns with an `int` inside for each field like that:

> 1 2
>   2 3
>   4 1
>   5 6

And I also have a larger grid, like that:

> 1 1 1 1 2 2 1
>   1 2 3 4 2 1 1
>   1 3 2 3 1 3 2
>   1 3 6 5 6 1 3

The two columns let me know that I have to replace every 2 with 1, every 3 with 2 and every 1 with 4 in the larger grid, so the result can be

> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   1 1 5 5 5 1 1

If I proceed directly replacing in the second table with the first entry, I won't be able to proceed with the second, since there are no more "2".

How can I solve that?

If the problem is not that clear, I give you this article that explains the problem, without showing any concrete solution.

http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/blobDetection.html#table

EDIT: I have an input like that:

Table of exchanges

> 3 2
>   4 1

Table to correct

```
1111111111111111111111111111
1122111111111111111111113311
1122211111111111111111133311
1112221111111111111111333111
1111222111111111111113331111
1111122211111111111133311111
1111112221111111111333111111
1111111222111111113331111111
1111111122211111133311111111
1111111111222113331111111111
1111111111122222211111111111
1111111111112222111111111111
1111111111112222111111111111
1111111111122222211111111111
1111111111222442221111111111
1111111112224444222111111111
1111111122244444422211111111
1111111222444444442221111111
1111112224444444444222111111
1111122244444444444422211111
1111222444444444444442221111
1112224444444444444444222111
1122244444444444444444422211
1122444444444444444444442211
1111111111111111111111111111
```

(this is an X)

In this case was pretty easy to make the replacement, since I don't have another reference to 2 except than 3 and 1 for 4, but most of cases do.
What I did was to directly go and replace the 3's with 2 and the 1's with 4.

Comment: If 3 becomes 2, and 2 becomes 1, and 1 becomes 4, shouldn't the final array be mostly filled with 4's. The problem statement is unclear, but more importantly, you haven't shown what you've tried, or explained why you're having difficulty solving the problem.

Comment: The problem example is inconsistent.

Comment: I edited my question, take a look now if is more clear.

Comment: Sometimes you replace column 1 digit with column 2 digit, sometimes the other way. In the first line you replaced the 2 (second column) with 1. In the second line you replaced 4 (first column) with 1.

Comment: Normally, the left column is the old value, and the right column is the new value. So 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 3, 4 becomes 1, and 5 becomes 6. Your task seems to be to determine the final value for each number. So `1->2->3`, `2->3`, `3=3`, `4->1->2->3`, `5->6`, and `6=6`. Once you know the final value for each input, the substitutions are easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, you can't apply the transformations one after another to your whole grid. Instead, you should find the correct transformation for each grid cell.

A rule that assigns a unique value based on the input is called a map. The identity map just maps each value to itself; these are the elements you don't  change. Start with an identity map and then adjust it according to your replacement pairs.

Here's a simple program based on your first example. Make sure that each input value is a valid index in the `map` array.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int grid[4][7] = {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1},
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1},
        {1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2},
        {1, 3, 6, 5, 6, 1, 3},
    };
    int map[10] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9       // identity
    };
    int i, j;

    map[2] = 1;                            // adjust map to
    map[3] = 2;                            // replacement pairs
    map[1] = 4;
    map[6] = 5;

    // apply mapping rule
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            grid[j][i] = map[grid[j][i]];
        }
    }

    // print grid        
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            printf("%d ", grid[j][i]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Duplicate the matrix (d). This will not be modified, just an aux.

2- For each cell in (d), compare (d)[cell] with every cell in 2nd row of your 2 columns.

2.1- On match, set in your result matrix (wich has been duplicated before), the value of the cell in the first column at the same (d) position.

3- Return the matrix modified.

Comment: I cannot know from the beginning what I will find in the two columns. If I had<br/>
3 2<br/>
2 1<br>
I wouldn't have solved the problem, since I expect to have all 3.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Dependencies, In changer column values <2 3 1 6>. **<1 6>** can easily change and  not depends. Afterward you need to save the states for every Integer.
Take array for store index position, i.e. **if(grid==1) then one[]=grid.value; if(grid==2) then two[]=grid,value;** respectively.
Now, change **grid[one[]]=2; and grid[two[]]=1;** Simply.

Comment: Could you be more clear with that code? I haven't understood your solution. Thanks in advance for your help.